# Как считать числа с файла построчно?

Tags: java, файлы

У нас есть точки и их координаты, нужно считать их построчно чтобы записать каждую координату в свою переменную.
Файл выглядит примерно так:

```
4, 6,
9, -2,
7, 3
```

Comment: Не понял, как числа расположены в файле? Судя по первому примеру, они расположены в одной единственной строке.

Comment: Не правильно указал, уже исправил

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов решения.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<int[]> coords = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/путь/до/файла.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                coords.add(getCoords(line));
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        coords.forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
    }

    private static int[] getCoords(String line) {
        String[] strings = line.split(",");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(strings[0].trim());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(strings[1].trim());
        return new int[] {x, y};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно по разному.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Coordinates {
    public static final String path="c:\\Coordinates.txt";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int a,b; 
            HashSet<int[]> list = new HashSet<int[]>();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                String [] points = line.split(",");
                a = Integer.valueOf(points[0].trim());
                b = Integer.valueOf(points[1].trim());
                int [] position = {a,b};
                list.add(position);
            }
            br.close();
            for(int[] p : list) {
            System.out.println("тут делаем то, что нам надо. Например: "+p[0]+p[1]); 
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ, используя новое API:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
...
public List<String> readFile(String pathToFile) {
        Path path = Paths.get(pathToFile);
        List<String> lines;
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error occured!");
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Это конечно не лучший способ обработки исключения, а лишь пример

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> line;
        Path path = Paths.get("list.txt");

        try (Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(path)) {
            line = stringStream
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```